# move_base crashes

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I am running: Ubuntu 12.10 64 Bit with ROS Hydra installed using apt.

I was following the navigation tutorial to get move_base running. But after publishing the first topics to it it crashes. I checked all topics in rviz and everything looks ok.

My map is really small: Resizing costmap to 544 X 608 at 0.050000 m/pix
But I also tried higher and lower resolution maps.

GDB gives me the following error:

```
[ WARN] [1386781814.297755287]: Trajectory Rollout planner initialized with param meter_scoring not set. Set it to true to make your settins robust against changes of costmap resolution.

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x00007ffff2ad3d3f in std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, double const&) () from /usr/lib/libpcl_common.so.1.7
```

I played around alot with the settings but nothing helped. Also I tried different maps sizes.

Thanks alot!

Full output:

```
core service [/rosout] found
process[amcl-1]: started with pid [26468]
process[move_base-2]: started with pid [26526]
[ INFO] [1386781754.861223568]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1386781754.867595885]: Received a 544 X 608 map @ 0.050 m/pix

[ INFO] [1386781754.926983060]: Initializing likelihood field model; this can take some time on large maps...
[ INFO] [1386781755.037315278]: Done initializing likelihood field model.
[ INFO] [1386781755.167248054]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [1386781755.242542521]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1386781755.445023367]: Resizing costmap to 544 X 608 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1386781755.544250197]: Received a 544 X 608 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1386781755.557500697]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1386781755.561873197]:     Subscribed to Topics: laser_scan_sensor
[ INFO] [1386781755.611294388]: Using plugin "footprint_layer"
[ INFO] [1386781755.623528775]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1386781755.809949187]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1386781755.873184453]:     Subscribed to Topics: laser_scan_sensor
[ INFO] [1386781755.908828212]: Using plugin "footprint_layer"
[ INFO] [1386781755.920289142]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1386781756.059400018]: Created local_planner base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS
[ INFO] [1386781756.080551731]: Sim period is set to 0.05
[ WARN] [1386781756.091632133]: Trajectory Rollout planner initialized with param meter_scoring not set. Set it to true to make your settins robust against changes of costmap resolution.
[move_base-2] process has died [pid 26526, exit code -4, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/move_base/move_base __name:=move_base __log:=/home/pasa/.ros/log/a699a86a-626f-11e3-9fa8-0024d7617cb0/move_base-2.log].
log file: /home/pasa/.ros/log/a699a86a-626f-11e3-9fa8-0024d7617cb0/move_base-2*.log
```

The log file mentioned does not exist.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109366/move_base-crashes/) by [Oinkmaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/9776/oinkmaster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-12-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-12-12**:
What operating system, architecture, ROS distribution? Package from apt repo?

**Comment by [Oinkmaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/9776/oinkmaster/) on 2013-12-12**:
Thank you for you feedback! Updated the post: I am running: Ubuntu 12.10 64 Bit with ROS Hydra installed using apt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed Ubuntu 13.05 on a new notebook and did exactly the same installation as stated above. I copied all my code over and now the crashes are gone.

So either there is a problem with my notebook, my installation or with the packages in Ubuntu 12.10.

---

Originally posted by [Oinkmaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/9776/oinkmaster/) with karma: 26 on 2013-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0